# SEO - Crawl Errors

Tags: google, seo, web-crawlers

I've been optimizing my website for search engines, and for some reason I have a crawl error on a page that has not been found at 'www.peach-designs.com/a' which is not a page, is not a link, or is not anything on my site.  I've checked my code and I'm only left to assume that this is a link to a page (a href, etc.).

Is this common for other websites?

Answer (score 1):

Such crawl errors come when some one else is linking you with wrong urls may be a forum or may when you are generating wrong links by mistake.

Generally I confirm is my mistake or wrongly linked by doing following

```
1. Just try to search for these link if you can find them in any other sites (That should cover most of your worries).  
2. Check them in your access logs and see if you can get referal urls.
```

If the number are low or within limits I generally ignore. But do monitor how many such request you get (404's).

Answer (score 0):

hi ho googlebot has a pretty broad understanding of what URLs it deems worth crawling. as a matter of fact, if you have any string with a slash (/) somewhere in your HTML or on page javascript, google treats it as an (relative) URL and tries to crawl it.

but hey, if you just have one or two or below half a million of such crawl errors, don't worry. it does not matter. if you have a few million crawl errors because of such strings, well do worry and change the strings.